# Raw array length

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have the following piece of code:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  datos                     raw(100);
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('The raw variable has a length of '||length(datos));
end;
/
```

Why doesn't it work? It should give me that the length is 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following

```
set serveroutput ON 
DECLARE 
    datos RAW(100); 
BEGIN 
    datos := utl_raw.Cast_to_raw('test'); 

    dbms_output.Put_line('The raw variable has a lenght of ' 
                         ||utl_raw.Length(datos)); 
END; 
/
```

will return

```
4
```

As you did not assign any value to it, the length is still null. Declaring a variable, identify the maximum limit to it. However, until you assign a value to it, it is occupying zero memory.

**UPDATE**

To calculate the remaining space of the variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_avl_spc(raw_val IN RAW)    
IS    
avl_spc NUMBER(100);    
BEGIN    
avl_spc := 100 - utl_raw.length(raw_val);  
RETURN avl_spc;  
END;
```

Then you can rewrite your line as follows:

```
dbms_output.Put_line('The raw variable has a lenght of ' 
                         ||fn_avl_spc(datos));
```

Of course you can improve the function to be more flexible and return the available space of any data type with any length

Comment: But imagine I want to write bytes to that variable, and I would like to know how many I can write at one. It would be better to do so without using an external variable to indicate me the maximum value. Because if the total lenght of the raw variable is changed then I would need to perform an extra change in the indicator variable

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Using another variable to store the available length is not a significant overhead. You can always update the variable with the current remaining length of `datos`

Comment: Despite not being a significant overhead the main issue is to be able to maintain the code as easy as possible, not having to remember that "if I touch this lenght I need to touch that variable too"

Comment: That wasn't what you asked in the question though. That is a different discussion and if you want a better way of managing your data overheads etc. ask a new question on it and explain the problem you are trying to solve and we can then, hopefully, give you a better explanation of what you need to do.

Comment: @Álvaro This is good example of using code modularization. Basically calculating the available space can be enclosed in a procedure, which you can refer to by mention its name only.

Comment: @Hawk Could you please provide an example with code?